# How to create a new file name instead of overwriting a file in Groovy

Tags: file, groovy

I move a file to a folder. Is there any way to not overwrite a file with that name?

For example, `folder` contains a file named: `file1.pdf`. How can I move another file named: `file1.pdf` into that folder so that the name get changed to e.g. `file1-1.pdf`, `file1-2.pdf` to prevent the original file from getting overwritten.

I'm using substring to do that but it's quite long and awful code.

Comment: "I'm using substring to do that but it's quite long and awful code." Could you please edit your question adding this code. That will help people to better answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
def save = { File dir, String name ->
    int version = 1
    def splitName = name.split(/\./, 0).with { it -> it.length == 1 ? [it[0], ''] : [it[0..-2].join('.'), ".${it[-1]}"] }
    def rename = { String prefix, String ext -> "$prefix-$version$ext" }

    while (new File(dir, name).exists()) {
        name = rename(*splitName)
        version++
    }
    println "Save the file as $name"
}

save(new File('/tmp'), 'file.txt')
```

Which assuming you have a file `/tmp/file.txt` and a file `/tmp/file-1.txt` already, prints out: `Save the file as file-2.txt`